# How can I decrypt ssl encrypted mongo wire protocol for inspection when I have ownership of all certificates involved?

Tags: mongodb

I have a standard [MongoDB SSL environment](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/) where the mongo wire protocol is encrypted with SSL/TLS using RSA keys. I have packet captures of communication between the MongoDB server and a client taken via `tcpdump`. I have ownership of the certificates involved in the encryption.

I have a capture of the handshake, and DHE / ECDHE / PFS is not at play in this scenario.

How can I decrypt the information in the existing packet captures to inspect the contents of the mongo wire protocol portion of the packets?

Comment: If your cipher suites were configured properly for forward secrecy, then you shouldn't be able to.

Comment: If you don't have PFS active, then something like http://www.rtfm.com/ssldump/ could help.  There's no easy way to select a given packet/dump and decrypt it without some heavy coding though. Regardless of method, you also need the session keys, which means having a dump of the handshake.

Comment: @Hyppy Correct, I do have the handshake as well.

Comment: What was the chosen cipher suite in the ServerHello in the packet capture?

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly can't because of forward secrecy.

MongoDB, for some reason, has a [hardcoded SSL cipher list](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/util/net/ssl_manager.cpp#L588) of `HIGH:!EXPORT:!aNULL@STRENGTH`. What this results in depends on the version of OpenSSL it was built against, but on a modern system will result in ciphers that use [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy) being preferred over those that don't.

You can see the generated cipher list on the target system with:

```
openssl ciphers -v 'HIGH:!EXPORT:!aNULL@STRENGTH'
```

When the SSL/TLS connection uses forward secrecy, it is impossible to decrypt the session, even if you have the SSL certificate private key. This is the whole point of forward secrecy; it prevents past sessions from being decrypted even if *an attacker* (whether it be you or a criminal or the NSA) gains control of your private key.

Comment: `s_client` pointed at this specific instance is showing `New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA` so I don't think forward secrecy is in play.

Comment: @Wesley In that case, find the server admin and beat him senseless until he fixes the problem.